# Why does my list disappear when I exit a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a piece of code that loops until an error is raised or a value of None is assigned to the variable "parent." On each loop, it appends a value to a list, known as actionList. Through print statements, I know that the list is growing through each iteration of the loop. However, after I exit the loop (through a KeyError that is caught), print statements reveal that the list is now assigned a value of None. Any idea what's going on?

```
while parent is not None:
                print "iterating"
                print actionList
                try:
                    pathList.append(parentMap[parent])
                except KeyError:
                    break
                actionList.append(actionMap[parent])
                parent = parentMap.get(parent, None)
            return actionList.reverse()
```

Upon further examination, it looks like the actionList is still intact once I leave the loop. However, when the reverse() method is used on actionList, it disappears. Am I using reverse() wrong?

Comment: um... okay, first of all, your indentation is way out of whack, and as you know that matters in Python, so could you fix it? Also, what do you mean by "disappears"?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  `reverse` reverses the list in place and returns None.  Do this instead:

```
actionList.reverse()
return actionList
```

You could also do `return list(reversed(actionList))`, which will return a reversed *copy* of the list.

Comment: Not quite. `reversed()` returns a `listreverseiterator object` (or a `list_reverseiterator object` in Python 3), not a list. Still, +1